# Perl deleting "blank" lines from a csv file

Tags: perl, file, csv

I'm looking to delete blank lines in a CSV file, using Perl.

I'm not too sure how to do this, as these lines aren't exactly "blank" (they're just a bunch of commas).

I'd also like to save the output as a file of the same name, overwriting the original.

How could I go about doing this?

edit: I can't use modules or any source code due to network restrictions...

Comment: Please note that if you can see a module on the web, then you can copy & paste that module into your code.  Modules don't have to be installed in order to be useful.

Comment: This crossed my mind the other day but for some reason I never actually looked into it whether it was possible... Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you'll find it hard to do without *any* source code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a command line hack,

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /[^,\r\n]/' file.csv
```

Comment: @user3707618 it does in-place edit. Make backup before executing.

Comment: Nice. Any way of doing something like that in a program?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a simple Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -ne 'print unless /^[,\s]*$/' <filename>
```

The `-n` flag assumes this loop around your program:

```
while(<>) {
   print unless /^[,\s]*$/;
}
```

and the `-i` flag means inplace and modifies your input file.

Note: If you are worried about losing your data with `-i`, you can specify `-i.bak` and perl will automatically write the original file to your `<filename>.bak`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it inside a shell script you can do this ...

```
#!/bin/sh
$(perl -i -n -e 'print $_ unless  ($_ =~ /^\,+$/);' $*)
```

Comment: how could I put this in the middle of a program and make it overwrite the original file?

Comment: Is that what you are after?  I'm assuming you have a script you want to add this fix to.  Otherwise you could put the perl in the shebang.